# Get software version with Puppet Fact

Tags: puppet, solaris-10

I'm trying to write a workaround because the versioning for package resources isn't possible with Puppet and Solaris 10.
What I need is the version string of an installed package.
I found out that factor already gathers this information, but sadly the info is stored in a nested array instead of a hash:

```
$facts['_puppet_inventory_1']['packages']
```

What's the easiest way to get the version string into a variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the easiest way to get the version string into a variable?

If you care only about a small number of specific packages then you could write one or more [custom facts](https://puppet.com/docs/facter/3.9/fact_overview.html) that provide the version string of each one.

Alternatively, if you want to extract package version strings from the `_puppet_inventory_1` fact you already have then you could write [a custom function](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/functions_basics.html) to do that job, or else use [an inline ERB or EPP template](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_template.html).

Which is easiest depends on your skills and experience, but I suppose that for most people, the custom function would be the *hardest* of the alternatives I offered.